# Why EF Core doesn't add an underscore when generating Foreign Keys?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-6.0

I'm migrating from EF 6 to EF Core (code-first approach) but when I run the system I get an error

> Invalid column name TableNameTableId

The problem is that the column is called `TableName_TableId`.

For some strange reason, EF Core is not adding the underscore when creating the migration, causing an error. There's any way to fix that behaviour? I've been looking everywhere and I can not find any other case where this is happening (for what I could find, the correct behaviour of EF Core is to add the underscore when generating a migration)

The database was generated using EF6 which adds the underscore on the column names.

This is an example of two entities (There are approx 50 on the system)

```
namespace Testing
{
    public class Model1
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm}")]
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Model2 Model2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model2
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Model2Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Model3 Model3 { get; set; }

        public virtual Model4 Model4 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you try adding attribute [Column("TableName_TableId")] ?

Comment: Yes, but that would require going through the 50 entities, checking the names of every foreign key and modifying that, while EF Core is supposed to create the name with the underscore by itself.